# pandas merge two dataframes with one contains column values in another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two `df`s,

```
df1

id    group
 1    0001
 2    0001
 3    0001
 4    0002
 5    0002
 6    0003

df2

group     name
0001      one
0002      one
0003      two
```

I tried to see if `name` contains `one` in `df2`, and finds the corresponding `group`s in `df1`; and then merge `df1` and `df2` in that regard;

```
a = df2['name'].str.contains(pat=r'(?i)one', regex=True)
valid_groups = df2.loc[a]['group'].tolist()

c = df1['group'].isin(valid_groups)
df3 = df1.loc[c]

df4 = df3.merge(df2, how='left', on=['group'])

group    name    id
0001     one     1
0001     one     2
0001     one     3
0002     one     4
0002     one     5
```

I am wondering is there a better way to do this, more efficient way.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
df2.merge(df1,on='group').loc[lambda x: x.name=='one']
#df2.merge(df1,on='group').loc[lambda x: x.name.str.contains(pat=r'(?i)one', regex=True)]
```

Or:

```
df2.merge(df1,on='group').query("name=='one'")
```

Answer (score 2):

If need `merge` only one column, faster is use `map`:

```
a = df2['name'].str.contains(pat=r'(?i)one', regex=True)
valid_groups = df2[a].copy()
df = df1[df1['group'].isin(valid_groups['group'])].copy()

df['name'] = df['group'].map(valid_groups.set_index('group')['name'])

print (df)
  id group name
0  1  0001  one
1  2  0001  one
2  3  0001  one
3  4  0002  one
4  5  0002  one
```